# How can I access JSON using data['file.file']?

Tags: javascript, json

I can query my data using var x = data.file.file; However, I have the file.file as a string and data['file.file'] fails. Is there a way to do this or do I need to split the string and walk in recursively?

Comment: `data['file']['file']` - would have to be done in two steps with the string like that, splitting on the dot.

Comment: Yes, you need to split the string and walk recursively. Parsers have been written before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without resorting to using eval (which you should definitely avoid), you have to split the string. Something like this should work fine:

```
var data = {
  file: {
    file: 'YAY'
  }
};

getProp(data, 'file.file'); // "YAY"
setProp(data, 'file.newprop.blop', 7); // false
setProp(data, 'file.newprop', {}); // true
setProp(data, 'file.newprop.blop', 7); // true
console.log(data); // {file: {file: "YAY", newprop: {blop: 7}}}

function getProp(obj, path){
  var parts = path.split('.'), u, i;
  for(i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
    obj = obj[parts[i]];
    if(obj === u) return u;
  }
  return obj;
}

function setProp(obj, path, newValue){
  var parts = path.split('.'), u, i;
  for(i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++){
    obj = obj[parts[i]];
    if(obj === u) return false;
  }
  obj[parts[i]] = newValue;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you (and not the answer I was hoping for).

Comment: BTW, I think your code is wrong. the vars u & i are never assigned.

Comment: @DavidThielen No it's correct, `i` is assigned at the start of the loop and `u` is purposefully `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

`data['file.file']` points to a property of data called 'file.file' while `data.file.file` points to the property file of the property file of data.

Use `data['file']['file']` instead to achieve the same access like `data.file.file`

Update:

Of course you will have to split your string to use the multi array access method. In your case this could be like:

```
var path = 'file.file'
var pathElems = path.split('.')

// access field
data[pathElems[0]][pathElems[1]]
```